# Read Excel file using Fillo API

Tags: java

I wonder can i use Fillo to read excel data from 2 columns with same name in 1 sheet without merge it? For example i need to read data from Column2

```
Column1|Column2|Colum3      Column1|Column2|Column3
```

Here is my code:

```
Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
    Connection connection = fillo.getConnection("TNK.xlsx");
    String strQuery = "Select * from TNK ";
    Recordset recordset = connection.executeQuery(strQuery);
       while (recordset.next()) {
           System.out.println(recordset.getField("Column2"));

       }
    recordset.close();
    connection.close();
```

But i only get Column2 in the first but i can't read the Column2 in second. I can't find any document about this API

Comment: Why is there a `for` loop wrapping around the `while` loop??

Comment: Is this two separate columns in separate tabs or separate files?

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot delete for loop. i'm trying to use i for getField but not success

Comment: @ChamaraMaduranga in 1 sheet